# How to check whether a number is the 2nd year every 5 years in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Given 10 years worth of yearly data, I need to change the value of the second year every five years.

Example:

```
A=[1]*10
# If we need to change the fifth number to 2 every five years the result should be
B=[1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2]
# If we need to change the second number every five years the result should be
C=[1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1]
```

Comment: Have you encountered Python slicing and (in particular) slice assignment? For example, your second example can be achieved with `C = A.copy(); C[1::5] = [2, 2]`.  Also, are you using NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to access the (1 + n*5):th number in an array. The second number in every group of five numbers is just every fifth number but starting with an offset of 1.

If you want to for example add 1 to every second year every five years you can do this with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
a[1::5] += 1
print(a)
```

gives the output:

```
[1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1]
```

The line `a[1::5]` means the array `a` starting at position 1 and going all the way to end with a stepsize of 5. So it accesses the indices 1, 6, 11, 16 and so on.